# Joining cached data with TTL in Apache Beam streaming pipeline

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-beam

I'm trying to migrate a family of Kafka processing pipelines from hand rolled server applications based on imperative code and data cached in Redis to Apache Beam running on Dataflow.

For each pipeline all the inputs originate from Kafka topics and can fall into two categories:

- cached (for X hours after which they should automatically expire)
- non-cached: processed immediately as the data arrives

The Kafka consumer enriches the non-cached inputs with the cached data doing either an inner or an outer join.
Number of topics to be processed can fall between 3 - 12.

For the sake of an example we can use a scenario with the following inputs from Kafka:

- `login_event` processed immediately (non-cached) keyed by `city`
- `trending_news` cached for 12 hours keyed by `city`
- `announcements` cached for 72 hours keyed by `city`

I'd like to do a 3 way join and write the aggregated, enriched object into an `enriched_login` Kafka message (to be processed further by other consumers).

My concern is around emulating cache expiration for the two cached topics in the example above.

My initial idea was to use sliding windows with a duration of 72 hours and a period of 1 hour.
But I’m worried that this could create up to 72 copies of a cached announcement and maybe also make the join operations executed for all “live” windows?

I very briefly looked into stateful processing for implementing cached elements with an expiration time implemented via [Stateful DoFn](https://beam.apache.org/blog/stateful-processing/) and Timers.

What kept me from investigating this option further was that I couldn't find a way to make the cached state available to Beam SQL queries. But maybe this is also possible?

I briefly looked at ksqldb for stream processing and my understanding is that when I do a query along these lines:

```sql
CREATE STREAM enriched_login
 WITH (kafka_topic=...)
 AS
  SELECT
     le.login_details AS login_details,
     le.key AS login_key,
     le.city AS city,
     tn.news_topics AS news_topics,
     an.messages AS messages
  FROM login_event le
    INNER JOIN trending_news tn WITHIN 12 HOURS GRACE PERIOD 10 MINUTES ON le.city = tn.city
    INNER JOIN announcements an WITHIN 72 HOURS GRACE PERIOD 10 MINUTES ON an.city = le.city;
```

IIUC here ksqldb implicitly creates a temporary buffer for the joined data (paritioned by key) with an expiration time set to the end of the window.

Essentially that is the behavior I’d like to approximate within an Apache Beam pipeline.

Ideally it would be some minimal Java code with as much of the Beam logic implemented in Beam SQL as possible.

In summary, I’d like my Beam pipeline to:

- Cache Kafka topic information for X hours
- Expire (garbage collect) cached data automatically when the X hours have elapsed
- Don’t create many copies or execute joins any more than necessary: ideally only one copy of each cached element plus whatever is needed for failover.